# Android Music Player save playlist

Tags: java, android, hashmap, store, playlist

Hey i had created a android music player application and everything was going great until i noticed every time i created a playlist and closed the application the playlist would not save because i never was.

i am using a hashmap so i can store the song name and the index it is belongs to. i have looked around on how to actually store a full hasmap or even an array list but couldnt find anything. i already know about the shared pref and am already saving some data there but is it possible if i can create a new file which will just store my playlist?

if you have any ideas or might have an example code that would be great.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `SharedPreferences.Editor.putStringSet` method. You can store Sets, which is good for storing something like a music playlist

Answer (score 0):

try this below link..
[Creating Playlist via code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897668/creating-playlist-via-code)

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = Context.getContentResolver();
 //Get all the playlists
 Cursor playlist = contentResolver.query(
   Media.AudioStore.Playlist.getContentUri(Media.AudioStore.Playlist.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI));
```